# Delay Algolia autosearch until third character

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I had a developer I worked with to build a client site (Im a designer with some CSS skills) and it uses algolia which is great but I am trying to find a way to make Algolia not start autosearching until 3 characters have been entered, then it can search away.

I believe this is the code doing it. I need to figure out a way to delay query into becoming valid? Until 3 characters are entered

```
    export default function SearchPlaceholder({toggleAlgolia, query}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.searchPlaceholder}>
      <div className={styles.searchBox}>
        <div
          role="button"
          tabIndex="0"
          className={styles.trigger}
          onClick={() => {
            toggleAlgolia(true)
          }}
          onKeyPress={(event) => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
              toggleAlgolia(true)
            }
          }}
        >
          <span>Click to Search Glossary</span>
        </div>
        <input
          tabIndex="-1"
          type="search"
          value={query}
          placeholder="Search our glossary..."
          readOnly
        />
        <button type="button" tabIndex="-1" disabled>
          <SearchIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't the typical Algolia libraries -- I suspect the actual connection to Algolia is sitting a little deeper in your code based.

Try to find where your app is importing `algoliasearch` and that should get you closer to where you are connecting to the service.

I should point out we typically discourage delaying search because it introduces a perceived “lag” in search results that your users might interpret as a slow response. It no longer becomes search-as-you-type, but if you do want to trigger a search only after a certain number of minimum characters you can change this default behavior by intercepting the search using our helper.js 82 library.

```
For example, you can limit the search to only trigger on a certain number of characters, such as at least 3 characters:

searchFunction: function(helper) {              
     if (helper.state.query.length < 2) {                         
        return; // no search if less than 2 character               
    }               
    helper.search( );     
}
```

Again, this may cause users to perceive the search to be lagging, but will reduce the number of search operations and reduce the cost.